# rxjava2 issue with Void

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have network api which returns Observable and I am trying to return a Observable after api call using below code

```
return apicall.execute().flatMap((Void none) -> {
            return Observable.just(data);
```

I am getting crash after apply FlatMap here as void emitting is not allow.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve the issue. `I can't change the backend call to get other response.

if I replace with below code :

```
return Completable.fromAction(() ->  apicall.execute()).andThen(Observable.just(segment));
```

it is not making the network call.

Comment: What's the signature of `apicall.execute()`. `Void` element type won't work with RxJava 2+.

Comment: it is returning Observable<Void> as it is a put call. How can make it work in rxjava2?

Comment: `Observable<Void>` can't ever signal any items because the only valid value for a `Void` type is `null` and `null`s are not allowed. You could convert it to `Completable`: `apicall.execute().ignoreElements().andThen(...)`.

Comment: I got it working by replacing Observable<Void> with Observable<Response<Void>>. `Thanks for your help.